# AzureBlob File Copy - clean up $web

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-blob-storage

I configured an Azure Release Pipeline for my Angular 8 App which copies the compiled app data to $web in an Azure Blob Storage Account.
It overrides existing files, which is fine.
But some of the compiled files that are created by the Angular compiler are named differently for every compilation.
This leads to an increasing amount of obsolete files in $web.

The AzureBlob File Copy task does not offer an option to initially clear/clean up $web.

How can I achieve the initial cleanup of $web?

Comment: Agree with Ivan's answer. You just need specify `$web` to `-s`. https://docs.aspnetzero.com/en/aspnet-core-angular/latest/Step-by-step-publish-to-azure-angular-staticsite

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MerlinLiang-MSFT The link is very helpful. I had to make the following change to make the azure cli command work: Remove the quotation marks from $web: `az storage blob delete-batch --account-name [STORAGE-ACCOUNT-NAME] --source $web`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Azure CLI task to invoke the `az cli commands` [az storage blob delete-batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-delete-batch) to clean up the container `$web` before running the `Azure File Copy task`. The sample code is as below:

```
az storage blob delete-batch -s mycontainer --account-name mystorageaccount --account-key mystorageaccountkey
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: I am using this for regular container, but it does not work for "$web" container. Fails with ##[error]Upload to container: '$web' in storage account:

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Windows based agent with powershell inline script, change double quotes to single.

```
az storage blob delete-batch --account-name <account_name> --source '$web'
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps pipeline task has issues identifying the container with name "$Web" which is created by default when creating a static website in Azure Storage.

I used an Azure CLI task and wrote the following powershell script to achieve this:

```
$connectionContext = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <Your resource group name> -AccountName <Your storage account name>).Context

$Container = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $connectionContext -Name '$web'

write-host  clearing files in container $Container.Name

Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $Container.Name -Context $connectionContext | ForEach-Object {
    write-host removing $_.Name
    $_ | Remove-AzStorageBlob
}
```